# Bitlocker key not saving to USB

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

In Windows 10 Pro, I'm trying to set BitLocker to use a USB drive to unlock rather than a password.

I choose `Insert a USB flash drive` on the `Choose how to unlock your drive at start-up` screen, select the USB drive, and press save. I expected it to save a key to my USB, but it doesn't.

After save, I see the `How do you want to back up your recovery key` option; here I can save to the USB drive and see the recovery key, but not the actual key.

Comment: `manage-bde` from command also fails, even though it says it's saved the external key (can't be found on either the USB drive or the C: drive being encrypted)

Answer (score 0):

The actual key, as you call it, is a hidden system *.bek file. (Start-key, external key file.)
The recovery key is referring to the long number sequence within a .txt file you can see like any other regular file after it is saved.

**You should not save it on the same drive however. Assume losing access to the USB drive.**

You can make the first one visible by showing hidden files (and system files).
Within cmd:

`dir /A:S E:` will list system files within drive E:.

Within cmd (run as admin) you can see what kind of keys you have added to your drive:

`manage-bde -protectors E: -get`

Comment: I tried on another machine which was able to save and use the .bek file on the USB